# What exactly mean refused in Oracle listener?

Tags: oracle, listener

What are exactly the reasons of the listener refuse some attempt of connection in database?

Other question is, the amount of refused connection is `lsnrctl services` command is all refused connection since when the listener has been started?

Comment: What is your second question about? Are you looking for a counter that displays the amount of rejected connections? Could you rephrase what you are actually looking for? Thanks.

Comment: A custumer contact me saying that one client machine did not get to use some application and the problem could be the connection in database. I seen in lsnrctl services output and there has some refused connections.. So yes, I am  looking for a counter that displays the amount of rejected connections.

Answer (score 1):

lsnrctl does show the number of connections refused since the listener was started. Connections can be refused for several reasons, usually because some part of the connect string is incorrect, missing, or malformed, like a bad service_name setting. A connection might also be rejected if the server has Valid Node Checking enabled and the client IP address isn't white-listed. Here is a list of common errors and some troubleshooting tips: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/netag/troubleshooting-oracle-net-services.html#GUID-F521AB0A-B67C-432B-B899-8F856EB51CAE

- TNS-12500/ORA-12500: TNS: listener failed to start a dedicated server process
- ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service
  requested in connect descriptor
- ORA-12520: TNS:listener could not find available handler for requested type of server
- ORA-12521: TNS:listener does not currently know of instance requested in connect
  descriptor
- ORA-12525: TNS:listener has not received client's request in time allowed
- ORA-12533: TNS:illegal ADDRESS parameters
- TNS-12540/ORA-12540: TNS:internal limit restriction exceeded and TNS-00510: Internal limit restriction exceeded
- TNS-12541/ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
- TNS-12549/ORA-12549: TNS:operating system resource quota exceeded and TNS-00519: Operating system resource quota exceeded
- TNS-12560/ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error occurred

Comment: Thanks! so can I find which machine was refused just reading the listener log right? I will do it today.

Comment: It will depend on the nature of the error. In some cases there isn't enough of a connection made to capture the source system identification, but for most of these you should be able to get the IP address from the log.